# CSS grid shorthand - grid area properties not working

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

I am currently setting up my CSS grid and attempted to use the grid shorthand to set everything out in one nice clean declaration.

e.g. `grid: auto / "sidebar" 15em "content" auto;`

This does not work. Chrome does not parse it. However...this does work.

`grid: "menu" 45px "context-header" 100px "main" auto / auto;`

I initially thought I could not put `auto` before the `/` but removing the `grid-area` properties to make it `grid: auto / 15em auto;` does parse fine.

Now a greater point can be made here about whether I actually NEED to use area properties at all. It is just a nice readable way to declare track space.
So I guess my question is more around syntax. Why can I have grid-area properties before the `/` but not after?

I have looked at the mozilla documentation and currently using https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid as my 'bible'. Unless I have misunderstood something obvious I haven't been able to work out why I am having this problem.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Here is my grid declarations in full for further understanding. The SASS variable names are hopefully self-explanatory.

**wrapper**

```
$grid-wrapper-columns: auto;
$grid-wrapper-rows: 45px 100px auto;
$grid-wrapper-area: "menu" 
"context-header"
"main";
```

**main**

```
$grid-main-columns: 15em auto;
$grid-main-rows: auto;
$grid-main-area: "sidebar" "content";
```

**content**

```
$grid-content-columns: 80% 20%;
$grid-content-rows: auto;
$grid-content-area: "content-left" "content-right";
```

Comment: Could you try to write your code without using shorhand property? It would help diagnosing what's wrong in your css

Comment: Amended with examples :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to swap names to left side of the slash, like this:

```css
grid: "sidebar" "content" auto / 15em auto;
```

Which renders to:

```css
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
grid-template-columns: 15em auto;
grid-template-areas: "sidebar" "content";
grid-auto-rows: auto;
grid-auto-columns: auto;
grid-auto-flow: row;
```

Comment: I see. So the syntax doesn't allow you to specify `grid-template-area` in the `<template-columns>` part of the shorthand declaration? Also, are two autos before the slash needed in your example? Or will it render the same with just one? `"sidebar" "content" auto`. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @EdwardScull Two autos aren't needed, edited my answer. And actually I'm not sure why it won't work the other way. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template#Syntax) isn't very clear on this

Comment: Ok well thanks a lot for your help. It is strange. Using your method has worked (almost). Please see this pen to understand better what I mean when I say..."almost". https://codepen.io/Dawdre/pen/XBPJLP